# Double Dot added in Mail body

Tags: c#, email, amazon-ses

I am using c# code to send account activation link to my customer through mail. Am using Amazon SES mail service. Some of my customers reported that their link not working. I found double dot added to the links.

Link 1:

> https://www.company.com/account/verify?email=customer.name@**gmail..com**&hashtoken=5574asfasfafb37d09aasdfa097

Link 2:

> https://www.**company..com**/account/verify?email=customer.name@gmail.com&hashtoken=5574asfasfafb37d09aasdfa097

Link 3:

> https://www.company.com/account/verify?email=**customer..name**@gmail.com&hashtoken=5574asfasfafb37d09aasdfa097

These are the double dots i have found each time when customer reports. When i am checking using my localhost, everything works fine and the link generates correctly. The issue is not generated for all the customers, it is generated randomly.

Note: I am appending the raw url in the mail template. I am not encoding it. I am encoding only the mail id.

```
string activationLink = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostUrl"].ToString()+ "/account/verify?email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email) + "&hashtoken=" + hashCode;
```

Thanks in advance

Dinesh.

Comment: What is the value of `email`?

Comment: for eg: string email = "customer.name@gmail.com" ;

Comment: you have to debug where it is appending two dots but here is temporary solution.    activationLink = activationLink.Replace("..",".");

Comment: while debugging the link generates correctly. anyways i will try your suggestion.

Comment: the issue is still reproduced. is there any other solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

Probably the encoding of the content is inappropriate...

Try:

`mailMessage.BodyEncoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`

For details, refer:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: will the encoding of body content using UTF8 is supported in all the mail clients like gmail, yahoo, outlook ,etc??

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug too. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution, but I've noticed it's caused by the AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString procedure and QuotedPrintable encoding. Moreover, extra dot is added when the line is starting from the dot.

My fix is:

- save mailbody to file before send
- replace .. to . at the in lines which starts with ..
- move file to pickup folder